# Handlebars looping over an Ember component simple property

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

In an ember component how can I generate 6 things in the template, given a component property called num with value 6?

Do I have to create an array just for the purposes of this in the component? If so can someone advise the most reusable way to do this?

I think I would need to do this via a helper:

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper('highlight', function(value, options) {
  var escaped = Handlebars.Utils.escapeExpression(value);
  return new Ember.Handlebars.SafeString('<span class="highlight">' + escaped + '</span>');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in my experience, this works well:

```
{{#each row in rows}} 
//do something 
{{/each}}
```

However, as you say, you'll probably need an array populated. I've used this with an array of Ember models to populate a table, but I'm sure you'll be able bend it to your purpose!

Comment: cool could you give me a helper that would do this to my prop, currently: **Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: The value that #each loops over must be an Array. You passed 6**

Comment: You won't be able to loop for 6, handlebars unfortunately isn't that advanced. You'll need an array with 6 objects in it.

Comment: ok, what about a helper that would do it? maybe I should just create an array for it.

Comment: I've always found it easier just to use {{each}}. If you're generating objects using it, generate them into the array then loop over it using that helper and just display them.